# Fontawesome not working in latest IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, font-awesome

I've got FA working on multiple sites hosted locally and remotely, and all of them seem to have stopped displaying icons on my laptop - I've done the obvious, tested on other devices and other browsers and I've found the latest IE appears to be the cause.

The IE version that does not work:

IE Version 11.15.16299.0
Update Code 11.0.47

Chrome works
IE version 11.0.9600.18762 works

So my own sites appear broken; but this public site that contains FA (the first result I came across on google) also appears to be broken...

https://fontawesome.bootstrapcheatsheets.com/

FWIW, glyphicons are not affected by this issue!
AFWIW, The official FA website works fine on the latest IE!!

Not been able to find anything on google so just wondering if anyone else is having this same issue and knows a fix?

So far I've tried:

Resetting IE settings & Delete cache/temp files
Try other devices (also have the same issue, with the same IE)
Try different FA sources; two CDN's and a local install - none fix the issue.

Thanks for any help :)

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Update on this – I’ve just run Windows Update again, installed another pending Windows update and its working again. So there was an update on Monday that broke everything, and another released at some point since Monday that fixes it.

Something else I noticed a few minutes ago (before the issue was fixed) – I logged into Office 365 webmail and all the icons there were missing too!  It’s pretty impressive stuff from Microsoft!